# How can I view a friends profile as it is seen by my other friends who are not their friends?

Tags: facebook

I would like to find out what my friends profile looks like when someone who is not their friend but one of my friends looks at their profile.

How is this done?

Comment: Why would you be able to see it?

Comment: @Shahar I want to know what my facebook friends see when they look at the profiles of my other facebook friends.

Answer (score 1):

That feature isn't available. At best, you can see what your own profile looks like to the public or to a specific person, but you can't see what someone else's profile looks like to a third party.

Answer (score -1):

Create a new account. This isn't a bad thing to have overall as sometimes you might wish to remain anonymous online.